# Is late data guaranteed to processed after the window trigger in Beam?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

If I am doing windowing with an allowed lateness along these lines:

```java
Window.<KV<Long, ParsedTransaction>>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(15)))
            .triggering(
                AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow()
                .withLateFirings(AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(1)))
            .withAllowedLateness(Duration.standardMinutes(5))
```

And this feeds into a combine function, then the result is written to a database using SpannerIO doing an insert or update mutation.

If a new item arrives immediately after the end of the window, it will cause a late firing. My understanding is the combine function and DB write will be run as a result of both triggers. Is there any guarantee that the late data will processed after the end of window triggered data is processed? Or is it possible the late triggered data aggregation could be overwritten by the end of window triggered output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't see this in the documentation, but this guarantee only lasts for the subsequent step after the windowing function. Meaning the DB write will have to occur directly after the windowing function. There are steps within the community to propagate these guarantees in further downstream transforms, see [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_7WRJznXlOtWuVaHl_dpy8OZcx_M8BUmeWVA4G0-wEc/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Thanks for the link, hopefully i can mark this incorrect in the future once it becomes possible 